iOS mic audio recorded in MPEG4AAC does not play in Android
I am recording voice in my .net maui app in iOS using AVFoundation.AVAudioRecorder.
    private AVAudioRecorder recorder;
    ...
{
           var filePath = GetTempFilePath();

            url = NSUrl.FromFilename(filePath);
            audioFilePath = filePath;

            NSObject[] values =
            {
                //NSNumber.FromFloat(44100.0f), //Sample rate
                NSNumber.FromFloat(16000.0f), //Sample rate
                NSNumber.FromInt32((int)AudioFormatType.MPEG4AAC), //AVFormat
                //NSNumber.FromInt32((int)AudioFormatType.Flac), //AVFormat
                NSNumber.FromInt32(1), //Channel
                //NSNumber.FromInt32((int)AVAudioQuality.Low), //PCMBitDept
                NSNumber.FromInt32(16), //PCMBitDept
                NSNumber.FromBoolean(false), //IsBigEndianKey
                NSNumber.FromBoolean(false) //IsFloatKey
            };

            NSObject[] keys =
            {
                AVAudioSettings.AVSampleRateKey,
                AVAudioSettings.AVFormatIDKey,
                AVAudioSettings.AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                AVAudioSettings.AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
                AVAudioSettings.AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
                AVAudioSettings.AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey
            };

            settings = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(values, keys);
            recorder = AVAudioRecorder.Create(url, new AudioSettings(settings), out error);
            recorder.PrepareToRecord();
        }

        recorder.Record();

Once the audio has been recorded, I read the byte[] of the temp file, store it in my db, and then pull it down to playback in Android using Android.Media.MediaPlayer. The Android player is as follows:
                var stream = new MemoryStream(audioBytes);
                var mediaSource = new StreamMediaDataSource(stream);

                player = new MediaPlayer();
                player.Completion += OnPlaybackEnded;
                player.SetDataSource(mediaSource);
                player.Prepare();

The StreamMediaDataSource class is as follows:
public class StreamMediaDataSource(Stream data) : Android.Media.MediaDataSource
{
    private Stream data = data;

    public override long Size => data.Length;

    public override int ReadAt(long position, byte[] buffer, int offset, int size)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(buffer);

        if (data.CanSeek)
        {
            data.Seek(position, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }

        return data.Read(buffer, offset, size);
    }

Recording on iOS and playing back on iOS works fine.
Recording on Android (recorder not above) and playing back on Android works fine.
Recording on Android (recorder not above) and playing back on iOS (player not above) works fine.
Recording on iOS and playing back on Android - FAILS.
The player gets the audio byte[], loads into in memory stream, but doesn't seem to load at player.Prepare. The return player has no data compared to when I had recorded something on Android and playback on Android.
Exception:
java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1441)
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
I have spent quite some time trying to debug this. I have tried several combinations of Sample Rate, AVFormat, PCMBitDepth (commented above to show) as well. Any suggestions?
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/iVd3T2Tj.png

https://developer.android.com/media/platform/supported-formats#audio-formats

I referenced that before when I tried different codecs like flac. Still same issue.

have you tried using some other 3rd party audio tool on Android?

I have not. Any recommendations for one?

Try to use Plugin.Maui.Audio?

It’s pretty much similar code to that plugin. Buy that plugin gives the same issues
